# Adding data in array list is failed

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add an object called `funny_momments_row` to an `ArrayList` called `data`, but it is not adding. I am checking that `data` is empty or not using `isEmpty` method afterwards. The code is running fine until this line:

```
funny_momments_row current = new funny_momments_row(dataSnapshot.child("like").getValue().toString(),dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
```

Here is the complete class:

```
public class funny_moments extends Fragment {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("funnymomments");
    ArrayList<funny_momments_row> data;
    TextView tesgting;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public funny_moments() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_funny_moments, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
        tesgting = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        getData();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    public void getData() {
        funny_momments_row lu = new funny_momments_row("1", "hi");
        myRef.child("video 0").setValue(lu);
        myRef.child("video 0").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot videoSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    funny_momments_row current = new funny_momments_row(dataSnapshot.child("like").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
                    data.add(current);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            tesgting.setText("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please add your exception in your ask.

Comment: Have you checked OnDataChange() called and inner for loop executed?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because `videoSnapsot` is the data you need to add in the array list.

```
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot videoSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                data.add(videoSnapshot.getValue(funny_momments_row.class));
                //Create getter/setter method in funny_momments_row class if needed.
            }
        }
```

And, for `funny_momments_row`, java naming convention, please.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not working, data is still empty and it should data.add(videoSnapshot.child("video 0").getValue(funny_momments_row.class));